# Python 3 & BeautifulSoup4 - Food Hygiene Scraper to CSV file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am very new to python and I am just learning things from tutorials online and code snippets.

My code is below, it works in that it scrapes the data I want but I think I could make the code much more efficient.

Code:

```
import requests
import time
import csv
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

hygiene = []

def deletelist():
    hygiene.clear()


def savefile():
    filename = input("Please input name of file to be saved")        
    with open (filename + '.csv','w') as file:
       writer=csv.writer(file)
       writer.writerow(['Establishment Name','Address','Inspection Date', 'Hygiene Rating'])
       for row in hygiene:
          writer.writerow(row)
    print("File Saved Successfully")


def appendhygiene(scrape):
    hygiene.append(scrape)

def makesoup(url):
    time.sleep(3)
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    page=requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(url + "  scraped successfully")
    return BeautifulSoup(page.text,"lxml")

def hygienescrape(g_data):
     for item in g_data:
        try:
            name = (item.find_all("div", {"class": "ResultsBusinessName"})[0].text.strip())
        except:
            pass
        try:
            address = (item.find_all("div", {"class": "ResultsBusinessAddress"})[0].text.strip())
        except:
            pass
        try:
            postcode = (item.find_all("div", {"class": "ResultsBusinessPostcode"})[0].text.strip())
        except:
            pass
        try:
            rating = (item.find_all("div", {"class": "ResultsRatingDate"})[0].text.strip())
        except:
            pass
        try:
            bleh = item.find_all('img', {'alt': True})[0]['alt']
            appendhygiene(scrape=[name,address + "\n" + postcode,rating,bleh])
        except:
            pass


def loop():
     search = input("Please Enter Postcode(First Part Only, e.g. BT36), Town, or Establishment Name")
     if search == 'London' or search == 'Glasgow' or search == 'Manchester':
        for i in range(1,10):
            soup=makesoup(url = "http://ratings.food.gov.uk/authority-search/en-GB/%5E/"+ search +"/Relevance/0/%5E/%5E/0/"+ str(i) +"/100000")
            hygienescrape(g_data = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "ResultRow"}))
     elif search:
         soup=makesoup(url = "http://ratings.food.gov.uk/authority-search/en-GB/%5E/"+ search +"/Relevance/0/%5E/%5E/0/0/100000")
         hygienescrape(g_data = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "ResultRow"}))

def loopforequalto():
     search = input("Please Enter Postcode(First Part Only, e.g. BT36), Town, or Establishment Name")
     ratingno = input("Please Enter Hygiene Rating")
     if search == 'London' or search == 'Glasgow' or search == 'Manchester':
        for i in range(1,10):
            soup=makesoup(url = "http://ratings.food.gov.uk/authority-search/en-GB/%5E/"+search+"/Relevance/0/%5E/Equal"+ratingno+"/0/"+i+"/100000")
            hygienescrape(g_data = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "ResultRow"}))
     elif search:
         soup=makesoup(url = "http://ratings.food.gov.uk/authority-search/en-GB/%5E/"+search+"/Relevance/0/%5E/Equal"+ratingno+"/0/1/100000")
         hygienescrape(g_data = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "ResultRow"}))

def loopforgreaterthanequalto():
     search = input("Please Enter Postcode(First Part Only, e.g. BT36), Town, or Establishment Name")
     ratingno = input("Please Enter Hygiene Rating")
     if search == 'London' or search == 'Glasgow' or search == 'Manchester':
        for i in range(1,10):
            soup=makesoup(url = "http://ratings.food.gov.uk/authority-search/en-GB/%5E/"+search+"/Relevance/0/%5E/GreaterThanOrEqual"+ratingno+"/0/"+i+"/100000")
             hygienescrape(g_data = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "ResultRow"}))
     elif search:
         soup=makesoup(url = "http://ratings.food.gov.uk/authority-search/en-GB/%5E/"+search+"/Relevance/0/%5E/GreaterThanOrEqual"+ratingno+"/0/1/100000")
         hygienescrape(g_data = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "ResultRow"}))

def loopforlessthanequalto():
     search = input("Please Enter Postcode(First Part Only, e.g. BT36), Town, or Establishment Name")
     ratingno = input("Please Enter Hygiene Rating")
     if search == 'London' or search == 'Glasgow' or search == 'Manchester':
        for i in range(1,10):
            soup=makesoup(url = "http://ratings.food.gov.uk/authority-search/en-GB/%5E/"+search+"/LessThanOrEqual/0/%5E/GreaterThanOrEqual"+ratingno+"/0/"+i+"/100000")
            hygienescrape(g_data = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "ResultRow"}))
     elif search:
         soup=makesoup(url = "http://ratings.food.gov.uk/authority-search/en-GB/%5E/"+search+"/LessThanOrEqual/0/%5E/GreaterThanOrEqual"+ratingno+"/0/1/100000")
         hygienescrape(g_data = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "ResultRow"}))




def hygieneratings():
        loop()  


def hygieneratingsbylessthanorequalrating():
    loopforlessthanequalto()


def hygieneratingsbygreaterthanequalrating():
    loopforgreaterthanequalto()       


def hygieneratingsbyequalrating():
    loopforequalto()

def menu():
        strs = ('Enter 1 to search Food Hygiene ratings by Postcode(First Part Only e.g. BT36), Town, or Restaurant Name \n'
            'Enter 2 to search by by Postcode(First Part Only), Town, or Establishment Name and Hygiene Rating Score\n'
            'Enter 3 to search by by Postcode(First Part Only), Town, or Establishment Name and Greater Than or Equal to Hygiene Rating Score\n'
            'Enter 4 to search by by Postcode(First Part Only), Town, or Establishment Name and Less than Or Equal to Hygiene Rating Score\n'
            'Enter 5 to Exit\n' )
        choice = input(strs)
        return int(choice) 

while True:          #use while True
    choice = menu()
    if choice == 1:
        hygieneratings()
        savefile()
        deletelist()
    elif choice == 2:
        hygieneratingsbyequalrating()
        savefile()
        deletelist()
    elif choice == 3:
        hygieneratingsbygreaterthanequalrating()
        savefile()
        deletelist()
    elif choice == 4:
        hygieneratingsbylessthanorequalrating()
        savefile()
        deletelist()
    elif choice == 5:
        break
```

The things that I don't like about the code is :

1. Loop functions e.g. Loopforequalto etc, contain the same repeated code except for the URL differing slightly. I am trying to find a way to put this into one function and call the function with a parameter for the URL, so I can just call the function containing the repeated code with the URL parameter as the URL for each corresponding loop. I have unsure how to go about this though.
2. I don't like how I am using the for I in range loops to scrape pages that have a lot of records, example London. I looked at the pagination and seen it was inside a Div container with no a href links for the "Next Button" in the pagination, and as I have only successfully scraped pagination with Next Buttons as a hrefs I am having an issue getting the Next Pages links, hence the use of the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're off to a good start. Keep reading and learning. :)
Here are some nits and improvements for you:

1. What is `time.sleep(3)` for?

   ```
   def makesoup(url):
       time.sleep(3)
       ...
   ```
2. Using `try/except/pass` as a `NoneType` guard is not a good idea. Also, it seems like you only want the first item.

   ```
   try:
       ...
   except:
       pass
   ```

   Use something like this instead:

   ```
   name = item.find("div", {"class", .... })
   if name is not None:
       name = name.text.strip()
   ```

   You could also refactor your code by storing the classes you're selecting in a list:

   ```
   classes = [
       "ResultsBusinessName", "ResultsBusinessAddress", ...
   ]
   data = []
   for item in g_data:
       for class in classes:
           data.append(item.find("div", { "class": class }))
   ```
3. `bleh` is not a good variable name. How about `imageAlts`?
4. No need to specify as a kwarg.

   ```
   appendhygiene(scrape=[name, address + "\n" + postcode, rating, bleh])
   ```

   is the same as:

   ```
   appendhygiene([name, address + "\n" + postcode, rating, bleh])
   ```

   Concatenating the address and postcode seems arbitrary to me, if you did the refactoring as mentioned above, you could shorten it to:

   ```
   appendhygiene(data)
   ```
5. The only thing different between all your `loopfor*` functions is the url. Write a URL formatting function:

   ```
   def createUrl(search, equivalence, ratingno, i):
       return "http://ratings.food.gov.uk/authority-search/en-GB/%5E/{}/Relevance/0/%5E/{}{}/0/{}/100000".format(search, equivalence, ratingno, i)
   ```

   You can use this in all sorts of ways depending on how you want to refactor your functions.
6. `hygieneratings()`, `hygieneratingsbylessthanorequalrating()`, and the other like functions are just aliases. Why not just name the functions that in the first place?
7. Use an [`if __name__ == "__main__":`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578308/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-main-method-in-python) guard for your code and wrap your main code in a `main()` method (just convention, not really necessary and varies since you're not importing these modules anywhere else).

   ```
   def main():
       while True:
           choice = menu():
           if choice == 1:
               hygieneratings()
           elif choice == 2:
               hygieneratingsbyequalrating()
           ...
           elif choice == 5:
               break
           else:
               print("Invalid choice!")
           if 1 <= choice <= 4:
               savefile()
               deletelist()

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       main()
   ```

Comment: could I ask one question please, when refactoring the code to put the classes in a list, instead of the try except blocks, the csv file I output becomes massive, over 400Mb, and never stops (like an endless loop until I force stop terminal). Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: You probably have an infinite loop in there that isn't terminating. Check your loop conditions.